# UIImageview not shwoing properly due to navigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am facing the issues with UIImageView in my application. Images are starched due to the navigation bar on top of the view. As soon as, I hide the navigation bar, the application shows poper sized images as provided in nid files.

Thank You.

Comment: isn't it possible, when drawing the nib, to show the navigation bar, so that you know, how to size the whole thing? I think thats the way I did it... but I only had a small picture on top of my app :-)

Comment: i am giving my coordinates according to navigation bar only, still its creating problem to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imageView probably resizes itself when its superView's frame changes. If you want your image not being stretched, use another `UIViewContentMode` like :

```
myImageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Or change your imageView resizingMask that it doesn't resizes itself.